# Convert QueryDict into list of arguments

Tags: python, json, django, dictionary

I'm receiving via POST request the next payload through the view below:

```
class CustomView(APIView):

"""
POST data
"""
def post(self, request):                
    extr= externalAPI()
    return Response(extr.addData(request.data))
```

And in the `externalAPI` class I have the `addData()` function where I want to convert *QueryDict* to a simple list of arguments:

```
def addData(self, params):        
    return self.addToOtherPlace(**params)
```

In other words, what I get in params is somethin like:

```
<QueryDict: {u'data': [u'{"object":"a","reg":"1"}'], u'record': [u'DAFASDH']}>
```

And I need to pass it to the addToOtherPlace() function like:

```
addToOtherPlace(data={'object':'a', 'reg': 1}, record='DAFASDH')
```

I have tried with different approaches but I have to say I'm not very familiar with dictionaries in python.

Any help would be really appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can write a helper function that walks through the *QueryDict* object and converts valid *JSON* objects to Python objects, string objects that are digits to integers and returns the first item of lists from lists:

```
import json

def restruct(d):
    for k in d:
        # convert value if it's valid json
        if isinstance(d[k], list):
            v = d[k]
            try:
                d[k] = json.loads(v[0])
            except ValueError:
                d[k] = v[0]

        # step into dictionary objects to convert string digits to integer
        if isinstance(d[k], dict):
            restruct(d[k])
        elif d[k].isdigit():
            d[k] = int(d[k])


params = {u'data': [u'{"object":"a","reg":"1"}'], u'record': [u'DAFASDH']}
restruct(params)
print(params)
# {'record': 'DAFASDH', 'data': {'object': 'a', 'reg': 1}}
```

Note that this approach modifies the initial object *in-place*. You can make a `deepcopy`, and modify the copy instead if you're going to keep the original object intact:

```
import copy

def addData(self, params):
    params_copy =  copy.deepcopy(params)  
    restruct(params_copy)   
    return self.addToOtherPlace(**params_copy)
```

Comment: p.s. I love your avatar. :)

Comment: Hi @Moses, thanks for your detailed answer but I'm not getting the expected result. When I call `restruct()` with the _QueryDict_ I receive in params I get the same _QueryDict_. MEaybe is something I'm missing?

Comment: I think the method does not work for *QueryDict*, add `params = dict(params.iterlists())` at the start of the function and let me know if that works